# How do I give a column of objects an offset in drawing panel?

Tags: python

I have a column of boxes in python and on every odd numbered row needs to be offset by 10 pixels. Would the best way to approach this be using an if/else statement with modulus?

These are the boxes:

```
for j in range(0, 6):
    for i in range(0, 3):
        p.canvas.create_rectangle(
            x + 50 * i + 25, y + j * 25, x + 50 * i, y + 25 * j + 25,
            fill="black", width=0)
        p.canvas.create_rectangle(
            x + 50 * i + 50, y + j * 25, x + 50 * i + 25, y + 25 * j + 25,
            fill="white", width=0)
```

Comment: Just add 10 to the x values of the ones on odd-numbered rows (`if j % 2 != 0:` or just `if j % 2:`) else don't do it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! How do I tell python "dont do it"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a couple of ways to implement conditionally adding an x-offset to the rectangles based on whether an even or odd row is being drawn:

```
xoffset = 10
for j in range(6):
    for i in range(3):
        rect1 = p.canvas.create_rectangle(x + 50*i     , y + 25*j,
                                          x + 50*i + 25, y + 25*j + 25,
                                          fill="black", width=0)
        rect2 = p.canvas.create_rectangle(x + 50*i + 25, y + 25*j,
                                          x + 50*i + 50, y + 25*j + 25,
                                          fill="white", width=0)
        if j % 2:  # odd row?
            p.canvas.move(rect1, xoffset, 0)
            p.canvas.move(rect2, xoffset, 0)
#        else:
#            pass  # don't do anything
```

Another approach would be to manually add in the x-offset value when creating the rectangles:

```
for j in range(6):
    xoffset = 10 if j % 2 else 0  # odd-numbered rows are offset

    for i in range(3):
        p.canvas.create_rectangle(x + 50*i + 25 + xoffset, y + 25*j,
                                  x + 50*i      + xoffset, y + 25*j + 25,
                                  fill="black", width=0)
        p.canvas.create_rectangle(x + 50*i + 50 + xoffset, y + 25*j,
                                  x + 50*i + 25 + xoffset, y + 25*j + 25,
                                  fill="white", width=0)
```

Either way, here's a sample how the output will look:

[image: screenshot of output produced]

Note that in the first example I've changed the order of the x and y values passed to `create_rectangle()` so that the first pair is the top left coordinate of the area and the second is the bottom-right of it in order to conform to what the [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_rectangle.html) says they should be—even though doing it differently seems to work in this case. (Position 0, 0 is the upper right corner with the positive x-axis going to the right and the positive y-axis going downward.)

*Also note that in `tkinter` a "drawingpanel" is called a `Canvas` widget (similar to the fabric upon which a painting, especially an oil painting, is drawn).*

Comment: Glad to hear it—and in that case, please accept my answer.